# Encountering issues with PyInstaller while creating desktop app with tabula and tkinter libraries

Tags: pdf, tkinter, pyinstaller, tabula

I have a python program that works perfectly, only after the installation of the application with pyinstaller I encounter a blocking with tabula (tabula.read_pdf(filename, pages='all')) the program stops at these lines:

```
load.pack_forget()
                lo20.pack_forget()
                v2.forget()
                tables = tabula.read_pdf(filename, pages='all')
                table = []
```

here is the complete function :

```
        def traitement():
            global traité
            global Dattta
            global laDate
            charger.config(bg='gray')
            if traité == 0:
                Dattta = []
                global année
                charger.config(text='Chargement...')
                année = simpledialog.askinteger(
                    "Année", "Merci de Saisir l'année", initialvalue=2023, parent=None, maxvalue=9999, minvalue=1000)
                traité = 1
                lo30.place(x=10, y=35)
                messagebox.showinfo(title='OK', message="OK 1", parent=window)
                if année == None:
                    charger.config(text='Charger les données')
                    traité = 0
                    return
                messagebox.showinfo(title='OK', message="OK 2", parent=window)
                
                charger.pack_forget()
                lo20.pack_forget()
                v2.forget()
                tables = tabula.read_pdf(filename, pages='all')
                table = []
                messagebox.showinfo(title='OK', message="OK 3", parent=window)

                for i in range(len(tables)):
                    csv_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f"table{i}.csv")
                    tables[i].to_csv(csv_file)
                for j in range(len(tables)):
                    csv_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f"table{j}.csv")
                    with open(csv_file, 'r') as file:
                        reader = csv.reader(file)
                        for each in reader:
                            if (each[1] != ''):
                                if (each[len(each)-1] != ''):
                                    if each.count("Unnamed: 2") == 0:
                                        if each[4] == '':
                                            if each.count("Page N°") == 0:
                                                for i in each:
                                                    if i == '':
                                                        each.remove(i)
                                                        for i in each:
                                                            if i == '':
                                                                each.remove(i)
                                                table.append(each)
                messagebox.showinfo(title='OK', message="OK 4", parent=window)
                
                year = année-2000
                i = 1
                for each in table:
                    each[1] = each[1][0:5]+'/'+str(year)
                    each[0] = 'D-' + str(year) + '-'+each[1][3:5]+'-'+str(i)
                    i = i+1
                    type = each[2][0:4]
                    if type == 'VIRE':
                        if each[2].count('DE') == 2:
                            each.insert(3, each[2][29:])
                        if each[2].count('DE') < 2:
                            each.insert(3, each[2][24:])
                        each[2] = 'VIREMENT PERMANENT'
                    if type == 'VIR ':
                        each.insert(3, each[2][26:])
                        each[2] = 'VIREMENT'
                    if type == 'VERS':
                        each.insert(3, each[2][13:])
                        each[2] = 'VERSEMENT'
                    if type == 'CRED':
                        each.insert(3, "")
                    if type == 'ENCA':
                        each.insert(3, "")
                    if type == 'OBJE':
                        each.insert(3, "")
                table.pop(len(table)-1)
                messagebox.showinfo(title='OK', message="OK 5", parent=window)

                for j in range(len(tables)):
                    os.remove(f"table{j}.csv")
                messagebox.showinfo(title='OK', message="OK 6", parent=window)
                
                style = ttk.Style()
                style.theme_use('default')
                style.configure("Treeview", foreground="black",
                                fieldbackground="silver", rowheight=25)
                scrolly = ttk.Scrollbar(frame2, orient=VERTICAL)
                my_tree = ttk.Treeview(
                    frame2, height=37, yscrollcommand=scrolly.set)
                messagebox.showinfo(title='OK', message="OK 7", parent=window)
                
                my_tree.tag_configure('gray', background='gray')
                my_tree.tag_configure('normal', background='white')
                my_tree.tag_configure('blue', background='lightblue')
                my_tree.tag_configure('green', background='lightgreen')
                my_tree.tag_configure('red', background='red')
                my_tree['columns'] = ("Date", "Mois", "Type", "NOM Donneur d'ordre",
                                      "Montant", "Détail", "Montant en lettre", "N° Attestation")
                messagebox.showinfo(title='OK', message="OK 8", parent=window)
                
                my_tree.column("#0", width=0, stretch=NO)
                my_tree.column("Date", width=80, anchor=CENTER, minwidth=25)
                my_tree.column("Mois", width=90, anchor=CENTER, minwidth=25)
                my_tree.column("Type", width=280, anchor=CENTER, minwidth=25)
                my_tree.column("NOM Donneur d'ordre", width=395,
                               anchor=CENTER, minwidth=25)
                my_tree.column("Montant", width=170,
                               anchor=CENTER, minwidth=25)
                my_tree.column("Détail", width=80, anchor=CENTER, minwidth=25)
                my_tree.column("Montant en lettre", width=405,
                               anchor=CENTER, minwidth=25)
                my_tree.column("N° Attestation", width=120,
                               anchor=CENTER, minwidth=25)
                messagebox.showinfo(title='OK', message="OK 9", parent=window)
                
                my_tree.heading("#0", text="", anchor=W)
                my_tree.heading("Date", text="Date", anchor=CENTER)
                my_tree.heading("Mois", text="Mois", anchor=CENTER)
                my_tree.heading("Type", text="Type", anchor=CENTER)
                my_tree.heading("NOM Donneur d'ordre",
                                text="NOM Donneur d'ordre", anchor=CENTER)
                my_tree.heading("Montant", text="Montant", anchor=CENTER)
                my_tree.heading("Détail", text="Détail", anchor=CENTER)
                my_tree.heading("Montant en lettre",
                                text="Montant en lettre", anchor=CENTER)
                my_tree.heading("N° Attestation",
                                text="N° Attestation", anchor=CENTER)
                messagebox.showinfo(title='OK', message="OK 10", parent=window)
                
                my_tree.pack(padx=5, fill='y')
                messagebox.showinfo(title='OK', message="OK 11", parent=window)

                scrolly.configure(command=my_tree.yview)
                scrolly.place(y=70, height=860, x=1655)
                laDate = table[1][1]
                for i in table:
                    if i[1][3:5] == '01':
                        mois = 'JANVIER'
                    if i[1][3:5] == '02':
                        mois = 'FEVRIER'
                    if i[1][3:5] == '03':
                        mois = 'MARS'
                    if i[1][3:5] == '04':
                        mois = 'AVRIL'
                    if i[1][3:5] == '05':
                        mois = 'MAI'
                    if i[1][3:5] == '06':
                        mois = 'JUIN'
                    if i[1][3:5] == '07':
                        mois = 'JUILLET'
                    if i[1][3:5] == '08':
                        mois = 'AOUT'
                    if i[1][3:5] == '09':
                        mois = 'SEPTEMBRE'
                    if i[1][3:5] == '10':
                        mois = 'OCTOBRE'
                    if i[1][3:5] == '11':
                        mois = 'NOVEMBRE'
                    if i[1][3:5] == '12':
                        mois = 'DECEMBRE'

                    def chiftolett(value, skip=-1):
                        if int(value) < len(units) and units[int(value)]:
                            return [] if int(value) <= skip else [units[int(value)]]
                        for name, v in bases:
                            if int(value) >= v:
                                return chiftolett(int(int(value)/v), 1 if v <= 1000 else -1) + [name] + chiftolett(int(int(value) % v), 0)
                    lenght = len(i[4])
                    po = i[4][lenght-2]+i[4][lenght-1]
                    l = len(i[2])
                    mytag = 'normal'
                    if i[2][0:6] == 'ENCAIS':
                        i[2]='chèque'.upper()
                    if i[2][0:l] == 'CREDIT COMMERCANT':
                        mytag = 'blue'
                    if i[2][0:l] != 'CREDIT COMMERCANT' and i[3] == '':
                        mytag = 'red'
                    if mytag == 'blue':
                        if po == '00':
                            my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=i, text='', values=(i[1], mois, i[2].replace('CREDIT COMMERCANT', 'CARTE BANCAIRE'), i[3], i[4], "", "".join(
                                chiftolett(int(int(i[4].replace(',', '').replace('.', ''))/100))), i[0]), tags=(mytag))
                            mytag = 'normal'
                        else:
                            ntl = "".join(chiftolett(
                                int(int(i[4].replace(',', '').replace('.', ''))/100)))
                            ntl += 'VIRGULE '
                            ntl += "".join(chiftolett(int(po)))
                            my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=i, text=i, values=(
                                i[1], mois, i[2].replace('CREDIT COMMERCANT', 'CARTE BANCAIRE'), i[3], i[4], "", ntl, i[0]), tags=(mytag))
                            mytag = 'normal'
                    else:
                        if po == '00':
                            my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=i, text='', values=(i[1], mois, i[2].replace('CREDIT COMMERCANT', 'CARTE BANCAIRE').replace('ENCAISSEMENT CHEQUE NUM - ', ''), i[3], i[4], "", "".join(
                                chiftolett(int(int(i[4].replace(',', '').replace('.', ''))/100))), i[0]), tags=(mytag))
                            mytag = 'normal'
                        else:
                            ntl = "".join(chiftolett(
                                int(int(i[4].replace(',', '').replace('.', ''))/100)))
                            ntl += 'VIRGULE '
                            ntl += "".join(chiftolett(int(po)))
                            my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=i, text=i, values=(
                                i[1], mois, i[2].replace('CREDIT COMMERCANT', 'CARTE BANCAIRE'), i[3], i[4], "", ntl, i[0]), tags=(mytag))
                            mytag = 'normal'
                messagebox.showinfo(title='OK', message="OK 13", parent=window)
                children = my_tree.get_children()
                for parent in my_tree.get_children():
                    Dattta.append(my_tree.item(parent)["values"])

                pdff = Button(frame1, text='PDF',
                              command=lambda: showPDF())
                pdff.pack(padx=20)
                lo = Label(frame1, text='Ctrl-P', fg='white',
                           background='black', font=('Times', 10))
                lo.pack()
                frame3.pack(fill='y', padx=10, pady=10)
                messagebox.showinfo(title='OK', message="OK 14", parent=window)

                Date = StringVar()
                Mois = StringVar()
                Type = StringVar()
                Nom = StringVar()
                Montant = StringVar()
                détail = StringVar()
                Montant_en_lettre = StringVar()
                NAttestation = StringVar()
                messagebox.showinfo(title='OK', message="OK 15", parent=window)
```

i tried to install the program with pyinstaller several times i tried the most accurate command i could which is this one :
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --add-data "/home/mechmach/dev/Jadara/TK/footer-att.png:." --add-data "/home/mechmach/dev/Jadara/TK/logo-att.png:." --add-data "/home/mechmach/dev/Jadara/TK/logo-light.png:." --add-data "/home/mechmach/dev/Jadara/TK/app.py:." --hidden-import tkinter --hidden-import PIL --hidden-import numpy --hidden-import tabula --hidden-import tabula.io --hidden-import tabula.environment_info --hidden-import java.awt.font --hidden-import java.awt --hidden-import java.awt.geom --hidden-import java.io --hidden-import org.apache.commons.logging --hidden-import org.apache.fontbox.ttf --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.font --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.outline --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.pagenavigation --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.pagenavigation.control --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.pagenavigation.destination --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.pagenavigation.paging --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.pagenavigation.provider --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.pagenavigation.table --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.pagenavigation.action --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.pagenavigation.logical --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.pagenavigation.outline --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.pagenavigation.style --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.pagenavigation.view --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.field --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.validation --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.validation.hardware --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.validation.action --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.fdf --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.fdf.FDFDocument --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.fdf.FDFField --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.fdf.FDFFieldNotFoundException --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.fdf.FDFCatalog --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.fdf.FDFDocumentCatalog --hidden-import org.apache.pdfbox

I also consulted chatgpt which gives me several ways to install my code with pyinstaller but I always have the same result

This program is for a foundation that helps young people and pays for their studies in Morocco and I am one of them (I don't earn anything from this, but I would like to support them as they did for me), so if someone can help me he will also help the foundation which means that he will give a push to many young people. thanks in advance.

I have tried several times to install my python program in desktop application with pyinstaller but I always encounter the same problem. I was expecting the application to work the same way as when I run it from my code editor but it's not the case, because after the installation with pyinstaller I have a block and I can't even see my "messagebox.showinfo(title='OK', message="OK 3", parent=window)" when I run the desktop application.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.